# Request signing in JMeter

Tags: java, jmeter

I need to send a sha256 hex request signature along with http requests.

From other questions and answers, there were suggestions to use bean shell preprocessor, but this does not seem to work anymore.

Are there any other ways to do this?

This is my code in the bean shell preprocessor

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils;

String api_key = "";
String shared_secret = "";
long timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000;

String sig = DigestUtils.md5(api_key + shared_secret + timestamp);

vars.put("sig", sig);

log.info("Signature: " + sig);
```

And this is the error

```
2020-07-23 10:18:55,694 ERROR o.a.j.u.BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh method: eval Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``import org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils;  String api_key = "35yNeSe37 . . . '' : Typed variable declaration
2020-07-23 10:18:55,694 WARN o.a.j.m.BeanShellPreProcessor: Problem in BeanShell script. org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method: eval   Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``import org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils;  String api_key = "35 . . . '' : Typed variable declaration
2020-07
```

Comment: This is due to DigestUtils returning a byte. We need to new String(DigestUtils.md5(api_key + shared_secret + timestamp));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Why you're using [DigestUtils.md5()](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/digest/DigestUtils.html#md5-byte:A-) if you're stating that you need "sha256 hex"?
2. Why you're using Beanshell if [since JMeter 3.1 you should be using Groovy](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting)?

I think you should change you code to something like:

```
vars.put("sig", org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils.sha256Hex(api_key + shared_secret + timestamp))
```

See [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) article for more information on Groovy scripting in JMeter.

By the way, there is [__digest() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__digest) which can make your life even easier:

[image]

Comment: can you please look into the following problem as well and let me know if it is achievable or not : https://stackoverflow.com/q/63053225/3928743

Comment: sorry. the code I pasted was md5 which I was trying before. And regarding the question about using beanshell instead of Groovy, I used it and I found it to be working. I will try the Groovy solution.